# Obtaining Localised results from bing maps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, localization, bing

I'm developing a simple WP7 application that maps out the route of a journey from the user's current position to his/her destination. All has been going well until I hit a snag with bing maps. I'd like a user to search for his destination but getting localised results in itself is an issue. From results I'm obtaining, I'm getting USA results alone. Anyone with an idea of how I can bypass this? 
I've seen someone say they implemented google local search but it was a bit ambiguous. 
I'd like pointers to other APIs to use if available as well.
Any clarification and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
After heavy reasearch, I've decided to use Openstreetmap (Nominatim) to obtain local search results and further use the latitude and longitude obtained to do more on my Bing Maps canvas

Comment: You are going to have to give some more detail - what API methods are you using?

Comment: For the search methods, Im adding the following reference: http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/searchservice/searchservice.svc?wsdl